# Can you use constant variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constants

I read on one site that you can make *constant* variables in JavaScript like:

```
const x = 20;
```

but on another site I read that you can't. So I am confused now what is it now?

Also in Visual Studio 2010 when I write `const` it underlines it in the JavaScript file and shows syntax error.

Comment: The answer is [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#let-const)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`const` is a proposed feature of ECMAScript Harmony](http://Wiki.ECMAScript.Org/doku.php?id=harmony:const) (together with a properly block-scoped `let` it is supposed to replace `var` and implicit globals). ECMAScript Harmony is a grab-bag of ideas for the next versions of ECMAScript.

`const` was also a part of ECMAScript 4.

ECMAScript 4 was never released and never will be, and ECMAScript Harmony will only be released in a couple of years. Therefore, you cannot reliably use it.

There are some implementations or derivatives of ECMAScript that implement `const` (ActionScript, for example). There are also some implementations that accept `const` as a synonym for `var` (IOW, you can use `const`, but it won't give you any protection.)

However, unless you absolutely can guarantee that your code will only run on very specific versions of very specific implementations of very specific derivatives of ECMAScript, it's probably better to avoid it. (Which is a real shame, because `const` and especially `let` are a *huge* improvement over `var` and implicit globals.)

Comment: Ya that won't do me any good. That sucks they really should have at least const in javascript.

Comment: This answer is outdated. There are transpillers, such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#let-const), which let you use new ES features in a normal browser.

Comment: [`const` is not for constants](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const) (as in “constant values”), though. It’s for constant *bindings*.

Answer (score 25):

if you're looking for a read-only variable, you simulate that with something like

```
var constants = new (function() {
    var x = 20;
    this.getX = function() { return x; };
})();
```

and then use it like

```
constants.getX()
```

Comment: What if `constants` variable is itself modified ?

Comment: @BharatKhatri if someone is redefining your objects on the fly it doesn't matter much what you do.

Comment: The main idea of a constant is to have it's value occupy only one section in memory for faster access rather than being declared multiple times. This solution is no where near of accomplishing that

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to create an object and put all your constants in the object:

```
const={};

const.x=20;

const.y=30;

Object.freeze(const);  // finally freeze the object
```

Usage:

```
var z=const.x + const.y;
```

Any attempt to modify the variable will generate an error:

```
const.x=100;  <== raises error
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no `const` in ECMAScript (disregarding the dead 4.0 version, and ActionScript).

The `const` is available in [JScript.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t07247t%28VS.71%29.aspx), and some [recent versions of JS engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/const) e.g. Firefox, Opera 9, Safari as a vendor-specific extension.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what Jscript.net is. Can it be used with jquery and stuff?

Comment: @chobo2: JScript is Microsoft's version of Javascript (trademark issue, I think). JScript.NET is an extension of JScript for the .NET framework, like C# and VB.NET. I don't think you can use jQuery with it, as JScript.NET is never available on a browser.

Comment: [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/const) is also available on the Mozilla implementations (Rhino, SpiderMonkey)

Comment: @CMS: Ah right. Updated.

Comment: @CMS Well I need my site to run on all browsers. So do other browser implement it too?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript ES6 (re-)introduced the [`const` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) which is supported in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const).

> Variables declared via `const` cannot be re-declared or re-assigned.

Apart from that, `const` behaves similar to [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

It behaves as expected for primitive datatypes (Boolean, Null, Undefined, Number, String, Symbol):

```
const x = 1;
x = 2;
console.log(x); // 1 ...as expected, re-assigning fails
```

**Attention:** Be aware of the pitfalls regarding objects:

```
const o = {x: 1};
o = {x: 2};
console.log(o); // {x: 1} ...as expected, re-assigning fails

o.x = 2;
console.log(o); // {x: 2} !!! const does not make objects immutable!

const a = [];
a = [1];
console.log(a); // 1 ...as expected, re-assigning fails

a.push(1);
console.log(a); // [1] !!! const does not make objects immutable
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is something which is not with var , is a global variable....there is no const in js.

`var a="test"` is different from `a="test"`

Comment: depends upon WHAT you call "js". There seems to be no constants in Microsoft WSH/WSC JScript, which is JavaScipt version 3, but later versions of the language introduced those

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no data type "**const**" in JavaScript.

JavaScript is a loosely typed language. Every kind of variable is declared with a **var**

Comment: Looseness of typing is a bit orthogonal to constancy of binding, don't you think?

Comment: It is indeed. What I meant was that there is no special data types ( int,string, const) in JavaScript.

Comment: There is no "const datattype" anywhere. But there are default values. There also are modifiers for the data types. "const" is one of modifiers. When you see "const i = 1" in old C code you are actually reading "const int i = 1". Equally there is no "long" or "short" data types, but those are "long int" or "short int".