# How to handle magic number in javascript

Tags: javascript, magic-numbers

I have search through google with keyword handle javascript magic number but couldn't find one.
In c# i would used constant defined number but i don't know what to use in javascript

something like this

```
public class MagicNumberHelper
{
  const int optionA = 1;
  const int optionB = 2:
  const int optionC = 3
}
```

Comment: Define "magic number" please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821509/can-you-use-constant-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @ Alin Purcaru

if(number == 1)
  DoA();
else if(number == 2)
  DoB();

1 and 2 are magic number.

Comment: Disregard my answer (deleted). It seems `const` is not a standard feature of JS. It will be added in `2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it just a constant number that you can test for later
in that case

```
var MagicNumbers = {
 optionA: 1,
 optionB: 2,
 optionC: 3
};
```

and then later test for it like this

```
if(inputNr == MagicNumbers.optionA) {
  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Translating that to JS (one of the ways to do it):

```
var MagicNumberHelper = {
  optionA: 1,
  optionB: 2,
  optionC: 3
}
```