# 'Missing semicolon' warning in Eclipse for JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, eclipse, warnings

Eclipse gives me the warning 'Missing semicolon' for line 4 of the following code:

```
const C = 'b';
function foo() {
    alert('x');
}
```

It does not for the following code:

```
//const C = 'b';
function foo() {
    alert('x');
}
```

For the following it gives me two warnings:

```
const C = 'b';
function foo() {
    alert('x');
};
```

Multiple markers at this line

- Unnecessary semicolon
- Missing semicolon

Is there a way to make Eclipse ignore my lines with 'const'? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

I am using:

Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers. 
Version: Indigo Service Release 1 
Build id: 20110916-0149

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is only a proposed **const** in JavaScript. Use

```
var C = 'b';
```

Actually, there is a const apparently, but it is not supported by all browsers and would not be good to use for that reason.

The reason Eclipse is giving you the warning is that it does not recognize **const** which is a known bug in Eclipse.

You can read how to ignore the errors in *[Use of JavaScript const gives "missing semicolon" in associative...](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326842)*.

Comment: Actually there's in a newer js version. const isn't supported by some browser but if you aren't going to target them it's ok to use the keyword.

Comment: Yeah, just read that too. Nevertheless it would be bad practice to use const.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821509/can-you-use-constant-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect reality ;)

Comment: @Asken It depends and what we target. If we target node.js it's a good idea to use the keyword.

Answer (score 7):

You may disable some warnings in the preference menu:

[image: Disabling warnings in preference -> Javascript -> Validator -> Error and warnings]