# Starting with Eclipse + Validation Issues with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse for PHP Developers (Oxygen package).  I am not getting  error messages for javascript. (for example, it is not showing error or warning even if semi-column for some lines are missing or statements like x=x is present)

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513035/missing-semicolon-warning-in-eclipse-for-javascript-code/9513081) . Accordingly, enabled all the validations.

[image]

Still Eclipse does not show warnings or error for javascript. I did clean build also but it did not help. For php, it is working fine.

Could anyone help me to know what I am doing wrong with the configuration.

EDIT: Errors are missing for files with js extension. Attaching sample file content below (content of a file test.js)

```
var test = 'hello';
test = test;

var test2 = 'e'

alert('hello');
```

Comment: In what kind of file the errors are missing (`.js`, `.html`, `.php`, ...)? Can you extend your question by an example file?

Comment: @howlger, please see the edit

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. In addition, the missing `' ` in `var test = 'hello;` is only shown as error if and only if the project has also the `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature` nature. Please report it to Eclipse.

Comment: thanks @howlger. i will do that. It is surprising that this error was not reported by anyone till now. I guess less people use js validation feature of eclipse.

Comment: I guess so, too. For JavaScript validation, you can install a plug-in like the [Tern Eclipse IDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tern-eclipse-ide).