# Avoiding using magic numbers in JavaScript - alternatives that work with JsHint

Tags: javascript, magic-numbers

JSHint's inspections now built into PhpStorm informed me about JavaScript magic numbers and I realise it'll make for clearer code to avoid using them.

I tried this:

```
var constants = {
    millisecs: 1000,
    secs: 60
};
```

and also this:

```
var constants = function () {
    this.millisecs = 1000;
    this.getMillisecs = function () {
        return this.millisecs;
    };
};
```

JsHint complains about both.

Taking the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821987/149998) though works fine:

```
var constants = (function() {
    var millisecs = 1000,
        defaultMsgsPerSecond = 60;
    this.getMillisecs = function() { return millisecs; };
    this.getDefaultMsgsPerSecond = function() { return defaultMsgsPerSecond; };
})();
```

Presumably because of the closure. Why is it that this is accepted, whereas the other two suggestions taken from another SO question are not?

Edit: Although not triggering an error, it doesn't actually work. It errors to say constants is undefined. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu6mu/).

*To clarify - by "works" I mean "doesn't trigger a warning from JsHint"*

Comment: One problem clearly appearing with your first two code examples, but missing in the latter code example, is that the "constants" are not that constant - that is, can be changed later in the code (with `constants.millisecs = 100;`).

Comment: @penartur that strikes me as being the answer - the working example immediately calls itself, making its properties private and thus only the two getters are exposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**about your edit**

I think you wanted to `new` the inline object:

```
var constants = new (function() {
    var millisecs = 1000,
        defaultMsgsPerSecond = 60;
    this.getMillisecs = function() { return millisecs; };
    this.getDefaultMsgsPerSecond = function() { return defaultMsgsPerSecond; };
})();
```

**But** JSHint will also complain about that: `Weird construction. Is 'new' unnecessary?`.

If you use it as a closure, then you need to actually return something. If you don't, `constants` will indeed contain `undefined`. An easy fix would be to return `this`, but that would be a bad solution because you're extending `this` which is an instance of an object you do not own.

So returning an inline object seems to be the solution here:

```
var constants = (function() {
    var millisecs = 1000,
        defaultMsgsPerSecond = 60;
    return {
        getMillisecs: function() { return millisecs; }
        getDefaultMsgsPerSecond: function() { return defaultMsgsPerSecond; }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

In EcmaScript 6, you'll be able to just do:

```
const MILLISECS = 1000;
const DEFAULT_MSG_PER_SECOND = 60;
```

But until then, you can use EcmaScript 5's Object.freeze:

```
var constants = {
  millisecs: 1000,
  defaultMsgPerSecond: 60
};

var constants = Object.freeze(constants);

// Now constants is in fact... a constant!
constants.millisecs = 999;
constants.millisecs; // Still === 1000
```

And if it's your nature to be verbose, you can try Object.defineProperties:

```
var constants = {};

Object.defineProperties(constants, {
    'millisecs': {
        value: 1000,
        writable: false
     },
    'defaultMsgPerSecond': {
        value: 60,
        writable: false
     },
});

// Again, constants is in fact... a constant!
constants.millisecs = 999;
constants.millisecs; // Still === 1000
```

Comment: All 3 ways are good, but just using `const MILLISECS = 1000;` is easy and clean. I tend to use the third way to create things like a User object that I don't want anyone to be able to change.